# How to localize .storyboard and .xib files without clicking on Localize button?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have a large iOS project that has hundreds of .storyboard and .xib files.  Some of these files are localized, but most are not.

I have tried un-checking and checking the 'Use Base Internationalization' as well as removing and re-adding 'English' to the project languages, but these options only affect .storyboard and .xib files that have been enabled for localization (by clicking on the 'Localize...' button in File Inspector).

In order to enable localizations for all my storyboard and xib files, it appears that I need to crawl through the entire project and click on the 'Localize...' button for every single file that is currently not enabled.  This would also need to be done for each new storyboard or xib file that is created.  I am hoping there is an option or tool I can run to simply enable localizations for ALL the storyboard and xib files in my project.  Is this possible to do in Xcode or with another tool?